# Optimistic update strategy using NGRX Effects?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

We are integrating the NGRX library in a project at the company where we work and we want to perform optimistic updates at the front-end instead waiting for the server response to perform some action. What we have tried is to use the `startWith` operator, but it throws the `Action properly` and then, as the `releaseService.deleteRelease` method does not return an action, it throws the `invalid action: null` error.

We have tried to add the `{dispatch: false}` config to the `@Effect`, but then the first action is not thrown...

We have also though about using a `tap` oeprator and dispatch some action directly to the store, but we consider it an anti pattern.

So, is it possible to achieve this without creating an `splitter` intermediate action? Thanks.

```
@Effect()
deleteRelease$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ReleaseCardActions.ReleaseCardActionTypes.DeleteRelease),
    exhaustMap((action: ReleaseCardActions.DeleteRelease) => {
        return this.releaseService.deleteRelease(action.id).pipe(
            startWith(new DeleteReleaseSuccess(action.id)),
            catchError(() => of(new ReleasesApiActions.DeleteReleaseFailure()))
        );
    }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but why not perform the optimistic update on the **DeleteRelease** action directly in the reducer, so your reducer and effect will fire on the same action independently. 
Then, you can do the "real" update from the response coming from the effet.

```
@Effect()
deleteRelease$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ReleaseCardActions.ReleaseCardActionTypes.DeleteRelease),
    exhaustMap((action: ReleaseCardActions.DeleteRelease) => {
        return this.releaseService.deleteRelease(action.id).pipe(
            map(new DeleteReleaseSuccess(action.id)),
            catchError(() => of(new ReleasesApiActions.DeleteReleaseFailure()))
        );
    }),
);
```

Comment: Hi! The problem is that at the same time the reducer modifies the state (and before the http request is made), I want to show an snack bar, what I'm trying to achieve with the `DeleteReleaseSuccess` action.